# When does the timer for Clem's weekly mission reset?

Tags: warframe

After completing *A Man of Few Words* quest, you can go to a Relay and speak to Darvo to go to a mission which rewards a Clem Clone blueprint. However, after doing the mission, there seems to be no indication when exactly you can do it again. The patchnotes stated that it was a weekly mission and have done it several times since it was introduced, but I still don't know when exactly I can do it again.

Does anybody know on which day its weekly timer is reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timer isn't like Baro's one (Affects everyone), it starts counting down the seven days when you complete the weekly from Darvo.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I could have verified that by myself on 27th February if I mobilised myself. Oh well. I'll need to remember to update the wikia when I'll be aple to play in June.